# Java saving audio directly to server?

Tags: java

Is it possible to record an audio file directly to a server without FTP? Looking for the fastest method. FTP has the delay of connecting to the server, which I'd like to avoid.

**@Jolta** to answer you question, its taking about 10-15secs or so from 1. writing the wav file , 2. ftp connection 3. uploading of file. Yes it varies based on wave file size ranging from about 200kb-400kb. not a problem from 1 file, but when 100-1000 individual recordings are created it start to add up. We tried establishing the the FTP connection once the applet loads that speeding things up a but it didn't take away the writing of the file to the users hard drive then having to upload the file.

Ideal would be to remove the process of writing to the users local computer and have for the recorded audio file to be created on the server itself. That would remove two steps (FTP and writing to local computer) and increase speed, and idea if that is possible?

Comment: Ah, now I understand why there would be more than a million questions on stackoverflow and increasing at a phenomenal rate!

Comment: Is it only latency you're concerned with? Because if you're bandwidth constrained (on the network or disk) you'd need to have caching somewhere. A different transport protocol won't help you then :(

Answer (score 0):

You want to accomplish this in Java?

I would guess ordinary, unencrypted FTP would be one of the fastest ways to write a file on a remote system. Unless they are sharing a file system, of course...

If you provide a bit of context, that might help. Such as, what are you trying to accomplish? What is the expected network latency if FTP session setup is "too slow"?

Comment: see original question, i added more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trouble with your FTP solution is saving the file on the client before starting the FTP server. But that has nothing to do with FTP in itself, but with the client. The client could also open an FTP connection as part of starting the recording, and stream the data real-time. That's also what you would do if you're going to stream the data to a web service.

If you want to stream the data to a web server you can just use any file upload method, for example the one provided by [Apache Commons Fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html). It has a streaming API which allows you to bypass the creation of a temp file on the server (if you wish so). The non-streaming API will upload files to a temporary file after which you can put them somewhere else.

This has unfortunately nothing to do with creating a temporary file on the client (step 1). That's part of the client and not the server.

Be aware that direct streaming to the server will make the client quite a bit more complex as the network may get saturated, requiring the client to cache (in memory or otherwise) the data that cannot be directly send.